# Magento 1.9 Obsever testing failed - Mage::log not generated

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

My observer :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gta_ExtraFeesRemove>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Gta_ExtraFeesRemove> 
    </modules>
</config>
```

config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gta_ExtraFeesRemove>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Gta_ExtraFeesRemove>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <gta_extrafeesremove>
                <class>Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model</class>
            </gta_extrafeesremove>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <salesrule_rule_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>beforecheckout</method>
                    </Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </salesrule_rule_save_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

observer :

```
 <?php
    class Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer
    {
        public function beforecheckout(Varien_Enent_Observer $Observer)
        {
            $event = $observer->getEvent();
            Mage::log($event->debug());
            Mage::log('Hy observer called', null, 'logfile.log');
        }
    }
?>
```

log file not generated at var/log location

Comment: which magento 1 version are you using ?

Comment: i am using magento 1.9.2.3

Comment: please create first the test.php file in root 
and check that log is generate or not

Comment: Normally what event used for getting shipping methods?

Comment: In test.php file what i need to add?

Comment: <?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::log('hello');

?>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97404/discussion-between-zus-and-jigs-parmar).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have spell error.

```
<frondend>
        <events>
            <salesrule_rule_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>beforecheckout</method>
                    </Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </salesrule_rule_save_before>
        </events>
    </frondend>
```

It should be

```
<frontend>
        <events>
            <salesrule_rule_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>beforecheckout</method>
                    </Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </salesrule_rule_save_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

Maybe you missed, it should be `<frontend>`.

Comment: May i know why magento not showing any error regard spelling mistake?

Comment: Still logfile not generated

Comment: Try changing the log code `Mage::log('text here', null, 'logfile.log', true)`

Comment: Still no luck...

Comment: the issue is of log not generate

Comment: now first create system.log file in var/log folder and run the test.php file and check

Comment: @JigsParmar If i run my observer https://paste.ofcode.org/37ccujDxcru9uDgYkE2PMiy   my log file name 35 instead of event.log, may i know what is the issue? screenshot -> https://snipboard.io/62r8hA.jpg thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add for admin in config.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <config>
                <modules>
                    <Gta_ExtraFeesRemove>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </Gta_ExtraFeesRemove>
                </modules>
                <global>
                    <models>
                        <gta_extrafeesremove>
                            <class>Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model</class>
                        </gta_extrafeesremove>
                    </models>
                </global>
                <adminhtml>
                    <events>
                        <salesrule_rule_save_before>
                            <observers>
                                <Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer>
                                    <type>singleton</type>
                                    <class>Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer</class>
                                    <method>beforecheckout</method>
                                </Gta_ExtraFeesRemove_Model_Observer>
                            </observers>
                        </salesrule_rule_save_before>
                    </events>
                </adminhtml>
            </config>
```

Comment: still not working these lines 1) Mage::log($event);  2)  Mage::log('Hy observer called', null, 'logfile.log');

Comment: var/log not generate logfile.log

Comment: Check if your logs are enabled under System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled

Comment: Yes, its enebled

Comment: Can you used this Mage::log($event->debug()); 
            Mage::log('Hy observer called', null, 'logfile.log');

Comment: still same error

Comment: log file not generated

Comment: Still no luck....